# Plans to migrate go-ethereum to rust-ethereum?

Tags: go-ethereum, golang, rust

Is anyone planning to migrate go-ethereum to rust-ethereum? Rust with all its features such as zero-cost abstractions, safe memory management, fearless concurrency really outshines Go.

Nathan Aw (Singapore)

Answer (score 0):

There do not appear to be such plans for go-ethereum.

Perhaps [Turbo-Geth](https://github.com/ledgerwatch/turbo-geth) in the future, though more immediate plans are C++:

> If we want to migrate to other languages, like Rust, in the future, it will be easier to do that from C++, again because of the language interfacing. Migration Go => (Go;Rust) => Rust is likely to be more troublesome than the migration Go => (Go;C++) => C++ => (C++;Rust) => Rust, though this is not currently a goal.

Source: [Towards the first release of Turbo-geth](https://ledgerwatch.github.io/turbo_geth_release.html)